# Android SimpleDateFormat not setting a custom pattern

Tags: java, android, time, simpledateformat

I have tried changing the format of the date given by `location.getTime()` from the default format:

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

to this format:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss
```

using the following code:

```
private String timeAsString (Location location) {
// code taken from: stackoverflow.com/questions/12747549/android-location-time-into-date
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
    Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
    return format.format(date);
}
```

However, my debugger says that `format` has the default format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. How do I get the format to change to `yyyyMMddHHmmss`?

Comment: That should return the string in yyyyMMddHHmmss format from what I am seeing. Where/when are you posting to your log?

Comment: I think you don't have a problem in this method. try cleaning the project and rebuild

Comment: Yeah. I just cleaned the project and it worked, which was odd because I thought I did that already. Not sure what changed, but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a problem in your method. try cleaning the project and rebuild.